# jquerymobile 1.2 google map full screen when resize

Tags: jquery-mobile, maps, fullscreen

I use google maps in jquerymobile. After upgrading to jqm 1.2, maps is not shown in full screen (in mobile & desktop browsers). But when I resize browser window, it turns into full-screen (that I want at first screen opened).

I search the problem on the Internet and try most of them but none of them helpful for me.

What is you suggestions?

Edit: I solved when I used jquery.ui.maps. And it is important not to use width:100% in canvas style. Instead of resize canvas on pagebeforeshow event

```
$('#map').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){
    $('#map_canvas').height($(window).height() - (10 + $('[data-role=header]').height() - $('[data-role=footer]').height()));
});
```

```
<div data-role="page" id="map" data-add-back-btn="true" data-fullscreen="true" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">                
        <h1 id="mapHeader">Konum</h1>                
        <a href="#menu"  data-role="button" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="e" >Menu</a>                  
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="map_content" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0;">             
       <div id="map_canvas" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; min-height:100%;"></div>
    </div>          
</div>
```